# list of pair of words that are in sequence using Python

Tags: python

I have list as follows

```
string = ['I went to work but got delayed at other work and got stuck in a traffic']
```

Now I want a output like as follows

```
stirng_seq = [(I, went), (went,to), (to,work), (work,but).....(in,a),(a,traffic)]
```

To clarify, I want a list of tuples where words are sequential.

My approach so far,

```
words = list(set(word.lower() for t in string for word in t.split()))
inv_txt = [(i,j) for i,j in zip(words[:-1],words[1:])]
```

However this is producing all combination of word pairs which I do not want. Like

```
[('went', 'got'), ('got', 'at'), ('at', 'and'), ('and', 'stuck'), ('stuck', 'traffic'), ('traffic', 
'but'), ('but', 'in'), ('in', 'other'), ('other', 'work'), ('work', 'to'), ('to', 'i'), ('i', 
 'delayed'), ('delayed', 'a')]
```

Any clue on this? Even `itertools.permutations()` seems not to have worked.

Comment: Yes that also doable.

Answer (score 2):

```
your_string = 'I went to work but got delayed at other work and got stuck in a traffic'
your_list = your_string.split()
your_result = list(zip(your_list, your_list[1:]))
```

Your mistake was at using `set` where you lost the order.